# Scan all wifi devices near the phone

Tags: android, iphone, wifi, mac-address

Company http://renewlondon.com/ have the terminal stations that collect all near by mac addresses

[image]

Can I via iOS SDK, and Android SDK,do the same thing?

Comment: On iOS you won't be able to do that unless you use private api and/or jailbroken device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the wifi data using 'WifiManager' and after the scanning the scanresult contain all the data like

**BSSID**   The address of the access point.

**SSID**    The network name.

**capabilities**    Describes the authentication, key management, and encryption schemes supported by the access point.

**frequency**   The frequency in MHz of the channel over which the client is communicating with the access point.

**level**   The detected signal level in dBm.

**timestamp**   Time Synchronization Function (tsf) timestamp in microseconds when this result was last seen.

about the wifi devices.
if you need more related to coding, I think I can help you...

Sample code

```
WifiManager wManager;
List<ScanResult> wifiList; 

wManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// Inside BroadcastReceiver()
wifiList = wManager.getScanResults();
for (int i=0; i<wifiList.size(); i++){
     ScanResult scanresult = wifiList.get(i);                        
     System.out.println("SSID: "+ssid);
     System.out.println("RSSI: "+scanresult.level);
     System.out.println("Frequency: "+scanresult.frequency);
     System.out.println("BSSID: "+scanresult.BSSID);
     System.out.println("Capability: "+scanresult.capabilities);
}
```

Also checkout the BroadcastReceiver().

Comment: Ciril how can I contact you? my skype is soulfreebek

Comment: @ UIugbek, you can contact me through the mail, cirilmannoor@gmail.com,
Also I'm litle confused with your problem. If you explain your needs the solution may more accurate.

Comment: Let me play off of this, I think Ulgbek wanted to be able to track WiFi _devices_ rather than access points. Is it possible with a router or Android device to capture MAC Addresses of nearby devices with their WiFi radio turned on?

Comment: With this solution, we can detect WiFi Access Points (like routers or devices, which are proxies to other networks) - not devices around like phones, tablets, etc.

Answer (score 3):

One way i can think of doing this is making your device as wifi hotspot and use some hidden api to discover devices.You are basically trying to mimic an access point.

Otherwise each device would need some p2p framework on them-either wifi direct on or some other framework like alljoyn or samsung chord which helps in peer to peer discovery